# Two kinds of Fuss ballot numbers?

Tags: combinatorics, catalan-numbers, algebraic-combinatorics

This is a newbie question (I have never had much to do with Catalan combinatorics), so be prepared for an easy answer.

Consider the directed graph whose vertices are pairs $\left(a,b\right)$ of integers, and whose arcs are $\left(a,b\right) \to \left(a,b+1\right)$ and $\left(a,b\right) \to \left(a+1,b\right)$ (for all $\left(a,b\right) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$). We denote this directed graph by $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and draw it on the standard coordinate plane. Directed paths in this graph are called *lattice paths*.

Let $k$ be a positive integer. A result of Barbier (see, for example, Theorem 2 in [I. P. Goulden, Luis G. Serrano, *Maintaining the Spirit of the Reflection Principle when the Boundary has Arbitrary Integer Slope*, Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series A 104 (2003), pp. 317--326](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097316503001511)) says that if $n$ and $m$ are two nonnegative integers satisfying $n \geq km$, then the number of lattice paths from $\left(0,0\right)$ to $\left(m,n\right)$ that never go below the line $y=kx$ (that is, that contain no vertex of the form $\left(a,b\right)$ with $b<ka$) is
$$\dfrac{n-km+1}{n+1}\dbinom{m+n}{m} = \dbinom{m+n}{m}-k\dbinom{m+n}{m-1}.$$
It makes sense to call these numbers "Fuss ballot numbers", since they generalize both the Fuss-Catalan numbers (obtained for $n=km$) and the ballot numbers (obtained for $k=1$).

(This result can easily be proven by induction over $m+n$. The paper I've linked is about finding more interesting proofs.)

I am wondering about the following:

> If $n$ and $m$ are two nonnegative integers satisfying $n \leq km$, then what is the number of lattice paths from $\left(0,0\right)$ to $\left(m,n\right)$ that never go **above** the line $y=kx$ ?

Suprisingly, this does **not** seem to be an equivalent problem: The symmetries observed in both mentioned particular cases ($n=km$ and $k=1$) do not generalize (actually, these symmetries are different, so this is probably less surprising than it seems at first sight).

Comment: Half an hour of work (with Joel Lewis) has revealed that this is a known problem without a known closed-form solution. For a summation formula, see Theorem 2 in: Darrin D. Frey, James A. Sellers, *Generalizing Bailey's generalization of the Catalan numbers*, The Fibonacci Quarterly, May 2001, http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/39-2/frey.pdf . See also http://oeis.org/A062745 .